# VBA powerpoint Strikethrough of a single word

Tags: vba, powerpoint, strikethrough

I have a powerpoint file with several sheets. On this sheets are text fields with texts. Some of the words are strikethrough. I would like to make a list of all the slides where a word exists which is strike through.
I tried to use the function:
If  objShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Strikethrough = True Then

Problem is that is only get true when the first word is strike through. So 
<del>Hallo jaja the function works</del>.
Hallo jaja  function does not work
Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, The  strikethrough does not work in this editor.

Comment: Hallo jaja : The function works (Now Hallo is strikedthroug). Hallo jaja : function does not work (Now jaja is strikedthroug)

Answer (score 0):

**Try `.TextRange2` instead of `.TextRange`** with **Font.<del>Strikethrough</del>** :

Example:

```
Sub ST() 
    With ActiveWindow.Selection 
        .TextRange2.Font.Strikethrough = msoTrue 
        .TextRange2.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Below is an (incomplete) list of differences in handling of the two property types:

```
| ﻿TextRange Property    | TextRange Return Type | TextRange2 Property                        | TextRange2 Return Type |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|------------------------|
| ActionSettings        | ActionSettings        | －                                         | －                     |
| Application           | Application           | Application                                | Application            |
| BoundHeight           | Single                | BoundHeight                                | Single                 |
| BoundLeft             | Single                | BoundLeft                                  | Single                 |
| BoundTop              | Single                | BoundTop                                   | Single                 |
| BoundWidth            | Single                | BoundWidth                                 | Single                 |
| （Characters method）   | （TextRange）           | Characters                                 | TextRange2             |
| Count                 | Long                  | Count                                      | Long                   |
| －                    | －                    | Creator                                    | Long                   |
| Font                  | Font                  | Font                                       | Font2                  |
| IndentLevel           | Long                  | （Paragraph Format2 .IndentLevel propety）   | （Long)                |
| LanguageID            | Mso LanguageID        | LanguageID                                 | Mso LanguageID         |
| Length                | Long                  | Length                                     | Long                   |
| （Lines method）        | （TextRange）           | Lines                                      | TextRange2             |
| －                    | －                    | MathZones                                  | TextRange2             |
| Paragraph Format      | Paragraph Format      | Paragraph Format                           | Paragraph Format2      |
| （Paragraphs method）   | （TextRange）           | Paragraphs                                 | TextRange2             |
| Parent                | Object                | Parent                                     | Object                 |
| （Runs method）         | （TextRange）           | Runs                                       | TextRange2             |
| （Sentences method）    | （TextRange）           | Sentences                                  | TextRange2             |
| Start                 | Long                  | Start                                      | Long                   |
| Text                  | String                | Text                                       | String                 |
| （Words method）        | （TextRange）           | Words                                      | TextRange2             |
|                       |                       |                                            |                        |
```

More information:

- [PowerPoint VBA: TextRange and TextRange2 Properties and Methods List](http://vba.relief.jp/powerpoint-vba-textrange-textrange2-properties-methods-list/)
- [Powerpoint text/link strikethrough or black out](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/powerpoint-text-link-strikethrough-or-black-out.3863983/)

Answer (score 0):

Since only SOME text within a text box may be underlined, you need to look at the .Runs collection for each shape that has text in order to extract just the struck-out text. Here's a start:

```
Sub ListStrikeThroughText()
' This will list the struck-through text from Slide 1
' Adapt as needed to collect all of the text from all slides

Dim sTextList As String
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oRng As TextRange2
Dim x As Long

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    For Each oShp In .Shapes
        If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame2.HasText Then
            With oShp.TextFrame2.TextRange
                For x = 1 To .Runs.Count
                    If .Runs(x).Font.Strikethrough Then
                        sTextList = sTextList & .Runs(x).Text & vbCrLf
                    End If
                Next
            End With

        End If
    Next
End With

MsgBox sTextList

End Sub
```